# How to create a bookmarkable material link with mat-icon

Tags: html, material-design, angular-material

I want to create a mat-icon link so I can bookmark it with the link name.
However, material design put the icon name in the middle of the  tag.

```
    <a mat-raised-button
      [routerLink]="['users']">
      <mat-icon >visibility</mat-icon>
      {{user.name}}
    </a>
```

In this case my bookmark will display the bookmark icon + 'visibility'.
I just want to have the username in the bookmark next to the icon.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what happens and what you are looking to do. Please add a screenshot, or the resulting text.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p397j.png

Comment: Did you find the answer?